# Can you use two different custom user as auth user in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-users

So let's say i want to authenticate two different user (e.g students with its studentID, and teachers with its teacherID). and both let's say both have different ID pattern.

how should I do that with Custom User ? should I extend from AbsractBaseUser and use BaseUserManager for both of them in the same class or make different class for each students and teacher ?

if so, what should I do with AUTH_USER_MODEL in settings.py ?

can i write it like "AUTH_USER_MODEL = ('accounts.StudentAccount', 'accounts.TeacherAccount' ) ?

I appreciate any of your help and answer !!!

Answer (score 3):

I think you may be over complicating the matter.

To authenticate a user, you need two pieces of information from them - one is public (like their username), the other is private, their password.

Once you have authenticated the user - confirmed they are who they say they are, that is, they have submitted valid credentials, next step is to figure out what they are authorized to do.

There are always two different steps - authentication and then authorization. Authentication confirms who you are, and authorization determines what you are able to do.

Now, in your scenario, students and teachers are logging in. The difference between a student and a teacher (besides having a different id pattern) is that they can do different things on the system.

So the problem is making sure you are giving the right *authorization* to the user.

The way they *authenticate* really doesn't matter. In other words, it doesn't matter if students are logging in with their email address and teachers are logging in with their teacherid, in the end - the authentication process is the same.

Now, let us get to Django. By default in Django a user is supposed to enter a username. This can be anything as long as it follows two rules:

1. Maximum length is 150 characters
2. It can only contain alphanumeric, _, @, +, . and - characters

Do we need to customize this part? Not really, as both studentid and teacherid will fit within those restrictions.

The next part is how do I differentiate between a "student" and a "teacher"? The easiest way to do this is to [extend the user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) by adding a custom flag to differentiate between a teacher and a student:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserType(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    flag = models.IntegerField(choices=((1, 'Student'),(2, 'Teacher')), default=1)
```

Now, when you create a user - simply set this flag to either 1 or 2, depending on what kind of user you are creating.

Remember, the authentication will not change - just the authorization.

You can then use this flag to further restrict what this user can do. Have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-user) for some examples.

Comment: Or can i use the groups feature in django to differ that this account belong to students group and that account belong to teacher group ? 
if yes, how can i do that ? did i must do it manually through admin page ? btw thanks for the advice :D

Comment: You may use groups, if you don't want to store any _addiitional information_ as part of the user's profile. If there is no difference between a student and a teacher (except what they can do in the system) then by all means you can use groups and the out-of-the-box user model without modifications.

Comment: I see... , well then i decide to use onl AbstractUser class and only add flag to differ the two user. Thank you for your reply, have a nice day